# How to display multiple imported photos with objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image-processing, uiimageview

I am trying to make an app that has the import page similar to VSCO app. But i can`t figure how to display all the pictures in a view after the user selects multiple photos from the gallery, the maximum should be 10 photos.

To get the image i used this code and it works good for one picture selection:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];

// transfer to the main screen
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    PreviewVC *prevVC = (PreviewVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PreviewVC"];


    passedImage = image;

    prevVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:prevVC animated:true completion:nil];
});
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];

// Go to the Main Screen
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    PreviewVC *prevVC = (PreviewVC *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PreviewVC"];

    // Passing Image to Preview VC
    passedImage = image;

    prevVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:prevVC animated:true completion:nil];
});
```

}

After i used a preview view to show the imported photo before you can edit it:

```
@implementation PreviewVC

// Hide the Status Bar
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return true;
}

-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    // Create a bitmap context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, image.scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the idea is to build up several images in the `PreviewVC`, then have it launch the picker and have it keep an array of images as a property.  That image array in turn becomes the datasource for a table view in the preview vc.  In rough outline...

```
// in PreviewVC.m
// in the private interface
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;  // attach this in IB, don't forget to set datasource to this vc
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *images;

- (void)userDidPressPickImageButton:(id)sender {
    // launch image picker vc from here
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
    image = [self imageWithImage:image scaledToSize:someSize]; // move this method here, too

    // here's the key
    [self.images addObject:image];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Make your table view datasource answer the `self.images.count` for numberOfRows, and, of course, cellForRow must configure a cell using `self.images[indexPath.row]`

Comment: I am kinda new to xcode, never worked with table views but i will see how to put this into my code. Seems like it can work, but i didn`t get which part i should put in previewVC.m and which in the mainview.m ?

Comment: @DavidJ, I may not understand enough about your app to say, but in my mind this is all in previewVC.   If the process is to allow a user to specify an array of images, then you'll need a VC with an array.  That vc should be the one to launch an image picker UI, adding to the array when finished.  The most common UI element to present an array is a table view, so the previewVC, along with the array is the table view's datasource.